# Why isn't move constructor called?

Tags: c++

The Standard provides an example regarding to the a move constructor. There is what it says:

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a move constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const`
>   `volatile X&&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all
>   other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

I was trying to run some an experiments with an example the Stadard provides:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


struct Y {
    Y(){ std::cout << "Y()" << std::endl; };
    Y(const Y&){ std::cout << "Y(const Y&)" << std::endl; };
    Y(Y&&){ std::cout << "Y(const Y&&)" << std::endl; };
};

Y f(int)
{
    return Y();
}

Y d(f(1)); // calls Y(Y&&)
Y e = d; // calls Y(const Y&)

int main(){ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1cfa278067b51c)

But instead copy constructor was called. Why that?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5cf2b59b260c3a

Comment: @P0W Ha, I was JUST about to post the exact same thing.

Comment: Suggested Reading : [_What are copy elision and return value optimization?_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/1870232)

Comment: @P0W What did you actually do? Could you explain?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv What you're seeing is an optimization technique used my modern compilers _Copy Elision_. Please go through above link

Comment: @P0W Ah, you've just added a flag no-elide-constructor. I forgot about copy-elision, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy-constructor is invoked by the line:

```
Y e = d;
```

This cannot be a move operation , because `d` is an lvalue. This is why you see the copy constructor call in your output.

For the line `Y d(f(1))`, `d` is moved from the rvalue `f(1)` (which was in turn moved from `Y()`), however [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) means that the output of both of these move-constructors may be suppressed.

Comment: Could you clarify why the example coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5cf2b59b260c3a calls move contructor two times?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv _`d` is moved from the rvalue `f(1)` (which was in turn moved from `Y())`_,  notice the post says _move_ "twice"